# Cannot subquery with orderated values of select

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my database, Shipping, and Names
The structure of the Shipping table is:

```
shipping_id Integer
name_id Integer
challenge_id Integer
score Integer
```

The structure of the Names table is:

```
name_id Integer
name String
```

I need to select the names from the Names table, which have more than one occurrence of in the Shipments table, that is, two shipments_id, whose score is equal to 120. They need to be sorted ascending by number of shipments_id and descending by name_id:

Through the query, I can select by the side of the table sending all nome_id in an orderly way and according to the criteria, the issue is that using this Select as a subquery of another select in the table names, does not respect the ORDER BY. Any way to use the results of this query in an orderly way to get the name in the Names table?

```
select name_id 
from Shipments 
GROUP BY name_id 
HAVING COUNT(shiping_id) > 1 
order by COUNT(shiping_id) ASC, name_id DESC;
```

I wanna something like:

```
select name 
from Names 
where Names.name_id IN ( 
    select name_id 
    from Shipments 
    GROUP BY name_id 
    HAVING COUNT(shiping_id) > 1 
    order by COUNT(shiping_id) ASC, name_id DESC);
```

Comment: THere's no point in using `ORDER BY` in `IN (subquery)`. Either something is in the values returned by the subquery or it isn't, the order of the subquery doesn't matter (unless you also use `LIMIT`).

Comment: When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. Why do you think nested order by should work? Tables have no order, result sets [sic] have order per an outermost order by. Nested order by without top/limit does nothing. This is a faq. PS For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your query is returning the correct records and all you need is the name.  It's a matter of a join at this point

```
SELECT name_id, N.Name
FROM Shipments 
INNER JOIN NAMES N 
  on Shipments.Name_ID = N.Name_ID
 and GROUP BY name_id 
HAVING COUNT(shiping_id) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(shiping_id) ASC, name_id DESC;
```

Note: There are many types of joins.  I'm using inner here because I'm assuming each shipment name is tied to one and only 1 name record. if a shipment could exist without a name we may want to use an outer join so we retain all shipments in that case we would change `inner Join` to `LEFT JOIN` in our example.    Other joins include "Full outer", "right", "Cross", "Cross Apply", "Outer Apply" and more...